# Scrapy: Same Xpath for different fields

Tags: python, pandas, xpath, scrapy, scrapy-splash

I am trying to scrape different category products from [www.galaxus.ch](http://www.galaxus.ch) using scrapy. To render the HTML I used Splash and Lua script. To read the excel file I used pandas. Till now my script is working fine. Here is my code_

## read_excel

```
import pandas as pd

def read_xlsx():
    df = pd.read_excel('externe_festplatte.xlsx')
    return df['Gtin'].dropna().astype('int64').tolist()
```

## spider

```
import scrapy
from scrapy_splash import SplashRequest
from galaxus.spiders.read_files import read_xlsx


base_url = "https://www.galaxus.ch/search?q={}"


class GtinSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'gtin'
    allowed_domains = ['www.galaxus.ch']

    script = '''
        function main(splash, args)
            splash:set_user_agent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.212 Safari/537.36")
            splash.private_mode_enabled = false
            assert(splash:go(args.url))
            assert(splash:wait(5))
            
            item_select = assert(splash:select("div.panelLayout_mainContainer__11Jh_"))
            item_select:mouse_click()
            assert(splash:wait(5))
            
            see_more = assert(splash:select("[data-test='showMoreButton-specifications'] span"))
            see_more:mouse_click()
            assert(splash:wait(5))
            
            
            splash:set_viewport_full()
            return splash:html()
        end
    '''

    def start_requests(self):
        for value in read_xlsx():
            yield SplashRequest(
            url=base_url.format(value),
            callback=self.parse, endpoint='execute', args={
            'lua_source': self.script
        }
        )

    def parse(self, response):
        yield{
        'Titel': response.xpath(".//span[@class='jqo5ci-1 goteOY']/text()").get(),
        'Untertitel': response.xpath(".//span[@class='jqo5ci-2 beeFWi']/text()").get(),
        'Beschreibung': response.xpath("//div[@class='sc-1op7ol6-0 hYPLAr']/span/text()").get(),
        'Kategorie': response.xpath("(.//div[@class='breadcrumbView_withIcon__3mWwP']/a)[4]/text()").get(),
        'Produktetyp': response.xpath(".//span[@class='yip624-0 dpAcNY']/text()").get(),
        'Hersteller': response.xpath(".//h1[@class='jqo5ci-0 czhxQj']/strong/text()").get()
       }
```

The problem is that if I also want to scrape the Spezifikationen/ Specification field from the same page, it is different for every product category but having the same Xpath `//td[@class='sc-18g78bs-4 sxRfA']`.
Example:

1. SSD
   https://www.galaxus.ch/de/s1/product/freecom-mobile-drive-classic-750gb-075tb-externe-festplatte-12097425?supplier=3204073
2. RAM
   https://www.galaxus.ch/de/s1/product/csx-ddr3-1333-mhz-sodimm-memory-4-gb-1-x-4gb-ddr3-1333-so-dimm-ram-12446698?supplier=3204073

For these two products categories, in the Spezifikationen field, they are having the same Xpath with different field names. For SSD it is "Formfaktor" and for RAM it is "Arbeitsspeichertyp" but the Xpath is the same for both. How to solve this issue? I also want to export the result to the same excel file.

*I hope I am able to make my point clear. I'm a new StackOverflow user. I'm trying to accustomed to it. Expecting your suggestions and guidance.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to use a *text* as a base for your XPath expressions:

```
memory_type = response.xpath('normalize-space(//td[.="Arbeitsspeichertyp"]/following-sibling::td[1])').get()
form_factor = response.xpath('normalize-space(//td[.="Formfaktor"]/following-sibling::td[1])').get()
```

Comment: I appreciate your suggestion but for more than 80 categories using text is very hard

Comment: @RaisulIslam you can get field name and field value using a bit modified XPath expression from my answer.

Comment: Sorry I didn't get it clearly. Can you explain a little more?